# Generating XML Documentation for single VB Class in WebSite Project

Tags: xml, vb.net, documentation-generation

I have Single VB Class inside website project and I need to generate XML Documentation for this class. 
is there any tool that can generate this documentation?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help_authoring_tool) lists a number of help documentation tools. I would expect all of them to be able to generate documentation from a VB class - I know RoboHelp, Doc-to-Help, and Help & Manual can all do so.