# Auto-generate documentation for single c# file in asp.net project?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, documentation

I'm trying to figure out how to automatically generate documentation for a single c# file in an ASP.NET project.  I'm using VS 2010, and I have SandCastle, but I'm starting to get the impression it can only be used for a full project.  The problem is that our entire project is huge and nothing but that one file needs documentation (it's the only one with functionality our clients use - everything else is internal)

I could do a batch script, but I'd rather not if there's a better way of going about this!

Does anybody have any ideas?  Thanks very much in advance!

(as a side note, I saw this already and it did not help: [Generating XML Documentation for single VB Class in WebSite Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4806064/generating-xml-documentation-for-single-vb-class-in-website-project) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using Sandcastle.

http://shfb.codeplex.com/

One thing you could do is have a post build task that pulls that portion of XML from the documentation file and then run Sandcastle or doxygen against your new XML file.

Comment: This would have been a great idea, but before it was posted I already went a different route - I ended up making a post-build triggered powershell script to grab that one file's xml information and turn it into a web page.  But if I hadn't done that, this method probably would have been much easier.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `StyleCop`? It's aimed more at ensuring consistent coding practices, but does provide a little handy tool that allows you to quickly "Document this" on a constructor, method or property, etc. Might be worth a look to see if it's what you're after.

[StyleCop](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/sourceanalysis)

Comment: Thank you for your input, but this does not solve my problem - the one file I need to document has a lot of methods in it (I can't individually generate docs for each one every time I make a new build).  I really need something that will automatically generate documentation for just this one file.

Answer (score 0):

Doxygen might help.  http://www.doxygen.nl/

At very least you can generate a word or pdf doc and then make a sub set of only the pages you need to provide.

Comment: Sorry, but I could already do that using SandCastle - I was hoping to fully automate the process for one file.  If I still have to do manual editing (ie. making a subset) every time I make a change, I'm back to square one  :(  Thank you for your input, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try https://www.docify.net/. Their whole thing is exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently made a simple to use library that generates markdown documentation from C# code. All it takes is a class library dll file. 
If you want to give it a try, [here's a link](https://github.com/CBinet/AutoDocumentation) on how to start using it with examples of generated documentation.

More informations : https://www.nuget.org/packages/BetaSoftware.AutoDocumentation

Comment: The examples don't show any doc strings. Are they included in the generated markdown files too?